# How to organize data from API source to output from Python into Excel?

Tags: python, json, excel, request

I'm using `requests` (see below) to call API source and fetch some data (see below). I'm not sure how to deal with it.

It looks like JSON and/or a dictionary but I have no idea how to process it in Python before exporting to Excel. I understand, I have not imported JSON at this stage but I can.

My code:

```py
url = 'https://quoteapi.com/api/v5/symbols/hvn.asx?appID=af5f4d73c1a54a33&averages=1&fundamentals=1&liveness=delayed'
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Data returned:

```json
{
  "symbol": "hvn.asx",
  "realSymbol": "hvn.asx",
  "units": "price",
  "currency": "AUD",
  "tz": "AEST",
  "tickTable": "0.0005<0.1,0.0025<2,0.005",
  "quote": {
    "pctChange": 0.556,
    "quoteBases": {
      
    },
    "low": 5.39,
    "open": 5.4,
    "vwap": 5.430336243,
    "value": 16256099.035,
    "time": "2021-07-07 16:49:15",
    "change": 0.03,
    "price": 5.43,
    "status": "ADJUST_ON",
    "close": 5.43,
    "bid": 5.43,
    "prevClose": 5.4,
    "lastTradeTime": "2021-07-07 16:49:15",
    "ask": 5.44,
    "volume": 2993572,
    "high": 5.48,
    "tradeCount": 5260
  },
  "sequence": 6502147,
  "desc": {
    "firstActive": "1990-08-06",
    "underlyingIssuerSymbol": "hvn.asx",
    "issuerName": "Harvey Norman Holdings Ltd",
    "isin": "AU000000HVN7",
    "securityType": "01",
    "shortDesc": "FPO",
    "lastActive": "2021-07-07",
    "abbrevDesc": "ORDINARY",
    "longDesc": "ORDINARY FULLY PAID",
    "shortName": "HARVEY",
    "underlyingIssuerNdividendPerShare": 0.38,
    "earningsPerShare": 0.5857
  },
  "averages": {
    "ytd": {
      "vwap": 5.395,
      "tradeCount": 4418,
      "high": 6.09,
      "value": 18583818.22,
      "volume": 3431631,
      "low": 4.7,
      "open": 4.69
    },
    "year": {
      "vwap": 4.884,
      "tradeCount": 4240,
      "high": 6.09,
      "value": 18055781.32,
      "volume": 3734356,
      "low": 3.49,
      "open": 3.59
    },
    "month": {
      "vwap": 5.293,
      "tradeCount": 4322,
      "high": 5.69,
      "value": 20414631.17,
      "volume": 3865196,
      "low": 5.07,
      "open": 5.36
    },
    "week": {
      "vwap": 5.508,
      "tradeCount": 3979,
      "high": 5.69,
      "value": 19188403.29,
      "volume": 3486067,
      "low": 5.37,
      "open": 5.4
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We cannot possibly tell you what to do with your data, since we don't know what the result should look like. But the good news is: your data is valid JSON, so you can convert your string to python objects (in this case nested dicts) using the ``json`` module and do whatever needs to be done from there.

Comment: You can store it as a dictionary variable and use dictionary methods to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from your code, you can parse the json string directly with a `requests` method:

```
obj = result.json()
```

You now have a python object called `obj`, which is a complex structure of nested dictionaries. That's very easy to manipulate in python, but it certainly doesn't look *tabular*, so it doesn't make much sense to try to export that to Excel. Also, as noted in the comments, you haven't indicated what the result should look like.

However, the `averages` key inside your data does seem tabular, here's how you can create a dataframe from it and export it to excel:

```
import json

with open("foobar.json", "r") as f:
    obj = json.load(f)

with open("averages.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(obj['averages'], f)

df = pd.read_json('averages.json').T
df.to_excel('averages.xlsx')
```

Note the `obj['averages']` in the `json.dump` call. Also, I used the `T` function to transpose the dataframe, it seemed more natural (but that's optional. Here's what the dataframe looks like:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
        vwap  tradeCount  high        value     volume   low  open
ytd    5.395      4418.0  6.09  18583818.22  3431631.0  4.70  4.69
year   4.884      4240.0  6.09  18055781.32  3734356.0  3.49  3.59
month  5.293      4322.0  5.69  20414631.17  3865196.0  5.07  5.36
week   5.508      3979.0  5.69  19188403.29  3486067.0  5.37  5.40
```

Comment: This gave me enough to work with and was able to complete my project.FYI - it is a combo of an API call (this query) and webscape from the same site. Use your answer to format to json, pull out data and combine with webscrape in loop and collect into a dataframe in pandas and then out to excel. Thanks Joao - you're a superstar :-)

Comment: Glad I could help :-)